# Error in running the sproutcore

Tags: rubygems, sproutcore

I have installed sproutcore, but getting this error while running
`sc-init, sc-server`in command prompt in my windows system.
 `C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in require': c
annot load such file -- iconv (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in
require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json_pure-1.4.6/lib/json/common
.rb:2:in ....`

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sproutcore buildtools are not Ruby 2.0 compatible. You will have to use a 1.9.x version of Ruby.